# GNU Radio Companion - Can't find osmocom block

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm using GNURadio Live DVD and GNU Radio Companion which is included on the live DVD.

I'm trying to find the osmocom block but I can't seem to find it. It should be under "Sources" in the block list but there is no "Sources". I'm using a HackRF One which is supported by GNURadio Live DVD.

Where can I find the osmocom block, and is there anything I have to do to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find stuff by using the magnifier Icon above the blocks list, or click into the block list, hit control-f; search for `osmo`.

gr-osmosdr should already be installed. If it's not, compiling it is pretty simple, but I think that would probably be best covered in a different Q&A.

Comment: Found it. I was spelling it wrong in the search. It's under "no module specified".